# Make a Django tables2 table header sticky when the page scrolls down

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, django

As the title says, I'm making tables in Django using django-tables2. I want it so that when I scroll down the page and the header of the table is about to go off the page, I want it to stick to the top of the page until the window scrolls up past it again. And no, I don't want to have a scrollable div within the page. Below is some relevant text:

tables.py

```
class Example(tables.Table):
    field1 = tables.Column()
    field2 = tables.Column()
    field3 = tables.Column()

    class Meta:
        attrs = {'class': 'table table-striped', 'style': 'display: block; overflow: auto;'}
```

example.html

```
<style></style>
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>Field1</td>
            <td>Field2</td>
            <td>Field3</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Text</td>
            <td>Text</td>
            <td>Text</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<script></script>
```

With CSS and JavaScript, does anyone have any solutions? I tried several solutions already but all of them ended up not doing anything to the headers at all. I'm using jquery-3.2.1. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```js
window.onscroll = function() {
  myFunction()
};

var navbar = document.getElementsByTagName("table")[0];
var sticky = navbar.offsetTop;

function myFunction() {
  if (window.pageYOffset >= sticky) {
    navbar.classList.add("sticky")
  } else {
    navbar.classList.remove("sticky");
  }
}
```

```css
.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 180px;
  margin: auto;
  background: white;
}

.sticky+tbody {
  padding-top: 60px;
}

table {
  table-layout: auto;
  width: 180px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

table.one {
  margin-bottom: -20px;
}
```

```html
<table class="one">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>Field1</td>
      <td>Field2</td>
      <td>Field3</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody> </tbody>
</table>
<table class="two">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>Text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>Text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>Text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>Text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>Text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>Text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>Text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>Text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>Text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>Text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>Text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>Text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>Text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>Text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>Text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>Text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>Text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>Text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>Text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>Text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>Text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>Text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>Text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>Text</td>
      <td>Text</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Well, this answer made me realize that I was sending the sticky class to the wrong element this whole time, but this is still flawed. The header goes straight to the top as soon as I scroll down instead of just sticking when the top of the page reaches the top of the header when scrolling down, and the header doesn't go back even after I return to the top of the page.

Comment: can you post your page, or at least part of it for us to see

Comment: Sorry, but for reasons I can't disclose, that's impossible. Besides, the code I wrote in the question is something I made up.

Comment: Also when I actually scroll down the header becomes scrunched up so the header and columns aren't properly aligned.

Comment: because it is a table, not a div. You can't simply do anything you want about it, or you will need buch of trick to accomplish that.

Comment: I have made some chnges, check out. I feel like I helped you to solve the problem. Please pick my answer. Good luck

Comment: I think you missed the part of the question that specifically states that it's a django-tables2 table, so I can't just divide it into two tables.